# get data from li click event using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

here is my html code sample i want to get data li click event. but its not fire even don't know where is error.

```
<ul id="menuitem" class="metro-sidenav clearfix tablenamecontent">
<li data-tableid="1"><a href="#" class="btn blue-violate ordersubmitbytable"><i class="icon-food"></i>T1</a></li>
<li data-tableid="2"><a href="#" class="btn blue-violate ordersubmitbytable"><i class="icon-food"></i>T2</a></li>
<li data-tableid="3"><a href="#" class="btn blue-violate ordersubmitbytable"><i class="icon-food"></i>T3</a></li>
<li data-tableid="4"><a href="#" class="btn blue-violate ordersubmitbytable"><i class="icon-food"></i>T4</a></li>
<li data-tableid="5"><a href="#" class="btn blue-violate ordersubmitbytable"><i class="icon-food"></i>T5</a></li>   
</ul>
```

> here is my jquery code sample what i have tried. please help through this code.

```
$('.ordersubmitbytable')
    .click(function() {
      var tableid = $(this).closest('li').data('tableid');
      alert(tableid);
    });
```

Comment: Try : var tableid = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-tableid');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.ordersubmitbytable').click(function() {
    var tableid = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-tableid');
    alert(tableid);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menuitem" class="metro-sidenav clearfix tablenamecontent">
  <li data-tableid="1"><a href="#" class="btn blue-violate ordersubmitbytable"><i class="icon-food"></i>T1</a></li>
  <li data-tableid="2"><a href="#" class="btn blue-violate ordersubmitbytable"><i class="icon-food"></i>T2</a></li>
  <li data-tableid="3"><a href="#" class="btn blue-violate ordersubmitbytable"><i class="icon-food"></i>T3</a></li>
  <li data-tableid="4"><a href="#" class="btn blue-violate ordersubmitbytable"><i class="icon-food"></i>T4</a></li>
  <li data-tableid="5"><a href="#" class="btn blue-violate ordersubmitbytable"><i class="icon-food"></i>T5</a></li>
</ul>
```

use `attr()` instead of `.data()`

Comment: thats my question if i use data-* Attributes why do i need attr() instead of .data() would you please explain.thanks for your reply.

Comment: it depends on how you set setting it using `.data("asd","1")` you get it using `.data("asd")` otherwise use `attr()` betcause they are stored on different location so setting and getting is not same

Comment: from my modal still not fire when i click li. dont nkow whats the problem. nut into the run code snippet its ok.

Comment: @pythongbs if your running on modal use event delegation change `$('.ordersubmitbytable').click(function() {` into `$(document).on('click','.ordersubmitbytable',function() {` then tell me what happens

Comment: yes it worked. thanks anyway. but if i use class name table content instead document whats the different? just curiosity i did it -but not worked.

Comment: @pythongbs tick the check mark if this answer helped you to close the OP

Answer (score 0):

You didnt close the UL

```js
$('.ordersubmitbytable').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var tableid = $(this).closest('li').data('tableid');
    alert(tableid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menuitem" class="metro-sidenav clearfix tablenamecontent">
  <li data-tableid="1"><a href="#" class="btn blue-violate ordersubmitbytable"><i class="icon-food">  </i>T1</a></li>
  <li data-tableid="2"><a href="#" class="btn blue-violate ordersubmitbytable"><i class="icon-food">      </i>T2</a></li>
  <li data-tableid="3"><a href="#" class="btn blue-violate ordersubmitbytable"><i class="icon-food">  </i>T3</a></li>
  <li data-tableid="4"><a href="#" class="btn blue-violate ordersubmitbytable"><i class="icon-food">  </i>T4</a></li>
  <li data-tableid="5"><a href="#" class="btn blue-violate ordersubmitbytable"><i class="icon-food">  </i>T5</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

First close the `ul` tag then use this script

```
$('.ordersubmitbytable').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var tableid = $(this).parents('li').data('tableid');
  alert(tableid);
});
```

Comment: from my modal still not fire when i click li. dont nkow whats the problem. nut into the run code snippet its ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','.ordersubmitbytable', function (event) { 
    var tableid = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-tableid');
    alert(tableid);
});
```